# How to automatically display project id into textbox on selection of project name from drop down

Tags: javascript, mysql, jsp

I want to fetch project name from database into drop-down box. Below is the code to fetch project names into drop down box.

```
    <TD><SELECT name="ProjName" id="selectBox"  style="fontfamily:Calibri;width:200px">
                <%
    try{
        String ID = "";
        String ProjName="";
        Connection con = null;
        response.setContentType("text/html");
    con = DBConnection.createConnection();
//Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
//Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/customers?user=root&password=root");
        Statement statement = con.createStatement() ;
        resultset =statement.executeQuery("SELECT ProjName,ID FROM myproject;") ;
%>
                  <%  while(resultset.next()){ %>

            <option><%= resultset.getString(1)%></option>

        <% } %>
        <%
//**Should I input the codes here?**
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
             out.println("wrong entry"+e);
        }
%>
</select></td>

Now I want to display respective Project Id into textbox.For example when I select projectname1 from dropdown then automatically set projectId1 into textbox.
```

I am not getting how I can automatically set respective project Id into textbox,on selection of drop down values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Java but as about concern to your jquery code then probably snippet will really helpful to solve your issue.

// Below java code is not guessing but I have tried to resolve with online java code editor

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.sql.*,javax.sql.*" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="ProjName" id="selectBox" style="font-family:Calibri;width:200px">
                        <%
                        try{
                            String ID = "";
                            String ProjName="";
                            Connection con = null;
                            response.setContentType("text/html");
                            con = DBConnection.createConnection();
                            Statement statement = con.createStatement() ;
                            ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery("SELECT ProjName,ID FROM myproject;");
                            while(res.next()){ %>
                            <option <%=res.getString(2)%>>
                                <%= res.getString(1)%>
                            </option>
                            <%
                            }
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            out.println("wrong entry"+e);
                        }
                        %>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(".ddProject").on("change", function() {
    if ("" !== $(this).val()) {
      $(".txtSelected").val($(this).val());
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'arial';
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br/>
<select name='ddProject' class="ddProject">
      <option value="">Choose project</option>
      <option value="1">Project 1</option>
      <option value="2">Project 2</option>
      <option value="3">Project 3</option>
    </select>
<br/><br/>
<input type="text" name="txtSelected" id="txtSelected" class="txtSelected" placeholder="project id?" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution,But these one is static ,I need dynamic.I want to fetch project name and project ID from database.

Comment: @JYOTIMISHRA first you mean to say you wanted to create first draw dropdown and then you want to work like that. but your question says "I can automatically set respective project Id into the textbox, on the selection of dropdown values."

Comment: <option value="<%= resultset.getString(2)%>"><%= resultset.getString(1)%></option>

Comment: @JYOTIMISHRA Could you check java code now in my answer?

Comment: @JYOTIMISHRA actually there are some typo and declaration bug.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<p>
Now I want to display respective Project Id into textbox.For example when I select projectname1 from dropdown then automatically set projectId1 into textbox.
</p>

<select name="ProjName" id="selectBox"  style="fontfamily:Calibri;width:200px">
<option value="">-- select project --</option>
<option myid="1001">Procject 1</option>
<option myid="1002">Procject 2</option>
<option myid="1003">Procject 3</option>
<option myid="1004">Procject 4</option>
</select>

<input id="selectedProj" type="text">
<script>
window.onload = function(e) {
  document.getElementById('selectBox').onchange = function (e) {
      var selectedOption = this[this.selectedIndex];
      var selectedId = selectedOption.getAttribute('myId');
      document.getElementById("selectedProj").value = selectedId
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```